# I got a Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: indexOf is a not a function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]I have to match the index two id if the id will be match product Key will be push in the array but i got a error  index Of is not a function error how to fix this ?

```
//Adding new product key to existing productKey of album.
$scope.newProductKeyArray =[];
// Push only if not found in array.
if(value.productKey != undefined) {

  // product key found adding another key..
  if(value.productKey.indexOf($scope.productKeyId) == -1) {
  //value.productKey.indexOf :- this line generate errror

   // Adding productKeyId to add this new productKeyId.
      value.productKey.push($scope.productKeyId);
      $scope.newProductKeyArray = value.productKey;

      if(albumObj != null && albumObj != undefined) {
        albumObj["shared"] = true;  
      }
    $scope.newProductKeyArray.push(albumObj);
    //After selected the user move the checkedUser into the allowBUserObjects 
    $(event.currentTarget).parents(".albumSection").hide("slow");

   // Calling inner function.
   updateArray();
  } else {
   console.log("Product already in album.");
  }
}

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: is `value.productKey` a string? or an array? if you answered *no* to both, then that is your problem (we can't see what `value.productKey` is)

Comment: sir value.productKey is an array.

Comment: Can you console value.productKey and paste the value here?  Or can you update the question with the values of the above mentioned attributes

Comment: clearly, at the point the code is run, it is **not**, as array's do have such a method :p

Comment: in the console i will show this id :-6608477199794176

Comment: Looks like an object

Comment: yes sir.her value is an object how to fix this error?